# Getting an element from a Scala Seq (list) by property

Tags: scala

Say I have the following:

```
lazy val store: Seq[Person] = Seq(
    Person(1, "Bob"),
    Person(2, "Jim")
)
```

where `Person` is defined as follows:

```
case Class Person(
    id: Long
    name: String)
```

How can I retrieve a Person from `store` by id?

Comment: @alexisc has given you the correct answer, but you might want to consider using Map of `id` to Person if you do this a lot..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `find` with a predicate that compares the person's id:

```
val p = store.find(_.id == someId)
```

This will give you an `Option[Person]` with the first element matching the predicate or none if no person with such id exists.

Comment: Many thanks. How can I get the contents of the `Person` form the Option if I want to return it from a method?

Comment: @harryg You can either check if the option is not empty and use get (there are other methods available you might check the documentation), or use pattern matching, for ex: `... match {
      case Some(p) => println("Person " + p.id + " " + p.name)
      case None => println("None")
    }`

Comment: use for comprehension `for(p <- store.find(_.id == someId)) { println(p) }`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer, but more of a suggestion to complement @Alexis answer.

Consider using a `Map[Int, Person]` to your store, this will improve the lookup times for a `Person` in case the store gets large.

e.g:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) = {
  lazy val store: Map[Int, Person] = Map(
    1 -> Person(1, "Bob"),
    2 -> Person(2, "Jim")
  )

val someId = 1
val result: Option[Person] = store.get(someId)
```

Comment: Heh. Snap! (see my comment)

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul LOL :)